# Randomize existing date's day and month in tsql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table with a `birthdate` field in it. I need to be able to randomize the date and month but keep the year. Is this possible in TSQL?

That is, if the given date in the field is 1/1/2012 I would like something like:

```
RANDBETWEEN(1, 29) / RANDBETWEEN(1, 12) / 2012
```

Comment: do you want to generate random dates within a given year?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take this approach, it does not randomize the month and day separately, but gives you a random day you can attach to your year.

```
DECLARE @year INT = 2012;
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, FLOOR(RAND() * 365), CAST(@year AS CHAR(4)) + '-01-01')
```

If you require leap-year checking for your randomization to include `12/31/LeapYear`, you can use this code instead:

```
DECLARE @year INT = 2012;
DECLARE @daysToAdd INT = 365;

IF @year % 400 = 0
   OR
   ( 
      @year % 100 != 0
      AND @year % 4 = 0
   )
BEGIN
   SELECT @daysToAdd = 366;
END

SELECT DATEADD(DAY,FLOOR(RAND() * @daysToAdd),CAST(@year AS CHAR(4)) + '-01-01');
```

Comment: just one problem, your code will never allow leap year to hit last day of the year with this formular

Comment: There's a flaw in this code.  It isn't returning results for 12/31/2012.  I think you will need to change * 365 to * 366. (see t-clausen.dk's comment about leap year)

Comment: @t-clausen.dk I have added a check for leap year to add the last additional day to the randomization.

Comment: You may want to swap out the RAND function for something else.  This solution will return the same results for each row if you are trying to set random values across multiple rows in a single SELECT or UPDATE statement.

Comment: Do not know how precise you want to be but A century that can be divided by 400 is a leap year... So the year 2000 whas a leap year

Comment: @Pleun Thank you for the information about the divisible by 400 being a leap year.  I only remembered the two rules from grade school - I looked up the real rules now.

Comment: I was born the 29th of Feb, makes it easier to remember the rules. I did not have a year 2000 problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Below are two methods for 2012 using NEWID() and CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM() functions.

```
SELECT RandomDateUsingNewId = DATEADD(DAY, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 366, '1/1/2012')
    , RandomDateUsingCryptGenRandom = DATEADD(DAY, CONVERT(INT, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(2)) % 366, '1/1/2012');
```

If you want code that works for years with our without leap year (not just 2012), then here's a modified set of code that calculates the days in the year based on the selected year.

```
DECLARE @Year INT = 2012;
DECLARE @StartingDateOfYear DATE = CONVERT(DATE, CONCAT('1/1/', @Year));
DECLARE @DaysInYear INT = DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(YEAR, 1, @StartingDateOfYear)));

SELECT RandomDateUsingNewId = DATEADD(DAY, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % @DaysInYear, @StartingDateOfYear)
    , RandomDateUsingCryptGenRandom = DATEADD(DAY, CONVERT(INT, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(2)) % @DaysInYear, @StartingDateOfYear);
```

Comment: I tested the code with a while loop and verified the code generates data for all days depending on the year.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT CAST('2012-01-01' AS DATE) ShortDate
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(D, 1, ShortDate)
  FROM cte
  WHERE ShortDate < '2012-12-31'
)

SELECT TOP 10 ShortDate
FROM cte
ORDER BY NEWID()
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: There's are two flaws in this code: (1) it returns data for 2013 instead of 2012 and (2) it return records for 1/1/14.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table(birthdate date)
insert @t values('20130101'), ('20120505')

update t
set birthdate = v.newbirthdate
from @t t
cross apply
(
 select top 1
 dateadd(year, datediff(year, 0,t.birthdate), number) newbirthdate 
 from master..spt_values
 where type = 'P' and
 number < datepart(dayofyear, dateadd(year, datediff(year, -1,t.birthdate), -1))
 order by newid()
) v

select * from @t
```